# Visual Studio 2010 - Display path to source file during compile?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I reworked my source file structure and moved files into sub directories. It is possible that files with equal file name are stored within different directories e.g.

```
src/item0/Base.cpp
src/item1/Base.cpp
src/item3/Base.cpp
```

When I compile the project the compiler output looks like:

```
1>  Base.cpp
1>  Base.cpp
1>  Base.cpp
```

not very clear. Is it possible to configure VS so that the compiler output is something like:

```
1>  src/item0/Base.cpp
1>  src/item1/Base.cpp
1>  src/item2/Base.cpp
```